# Setup DNSMasq as caching DNS server and DHCP for local network for IPV6 with a seperate router/gateway

Tags: dns, dhcp, ipv6, dnsmasq

I have setup a home network on which I have been running my DNSMasq IPV4 caching DNS server for a few years.  It is not the router/gateway and I want to add support for IPV6 and what I think I understand is the following
The gateway gets an public IPV6 subnet - from which it allocates addresses to all the local devices
For IPV4 I understand - the addresses are private so I just allocate from my own internal addresses
But for IPV6 -
I need some way of telling DNSMasq that it should ... . Thats were I get stuck I assume it needs to get its address from the gateway or something and then allocate using the same prefix
Should I disable IPV6 and then probe to determine the prefix ... seems naff
Windows seems to prefer IPV6 DNS name resolution - so if I leave the DHCP server V6 server on the router working - then local name resolution of my IPV4 devices stops working.

The gateway is an ISP owned device I can disable IPV6 - I see no way to pass the DHCP IVP6 through to the DNSMasq machine
One of the uses is I have a few home-control machines which I refer to by name rather than IP (as they all have passwords stored in a password manager and it matches by the name ) and a lot of these don't support IPV6
What I want is to keep using my DNSMasq as a server with local name resolution working - I also would like to keep my reserved addresses

So can this be done and if so what should I be doing?  Te main issue I have is lack of resolution for my IPV4 machines - so perhaps that is unavoidable?  That is if I get this working and if an IPV6/IPV4 machine sends a DNS request to the IPV6 (but common IPV6/IPV4) DHCP/DNS server (my DNSMasq machine) but it only has an IPV4 address - will that work?

I have Telstra NBN
I did find an message about  [prefix delegation](https://superuser.com/questions/1097687/radvd-for-ipv6-assignement-dnsmasq-for-dhcp-handing-out-dns-for-ipv6-clients) and I found [this](https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/hw_feature_242)  saying "All Telstra NBN retail services have IPv6 enabled by default. Both NBN and ADSL(IPoE) supply are /56 via prefix-delegation"
Is that what I'm after - the article says its enabled - how do I use it?